# Internally-used function in Blockly

Tags: javascript, blockly

If you go to [the Blockly demo](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/code/index.html), take out the random colour block, and then click the JavaScript tab, you will see the following code generated:

```
function colourRandom() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 24));
  return '#' + ('00000' + num.toString(16)).substr(-6);
}


colourRandom();
```

It creates its own function, `colourRandom`. Now if you go back to the Blocks tab and create a variable named `colourRandom`, the same name as the function, drag out a `set colourRandom to` block, and go back to the Javascript tab, the `colourRandom` function changes its name to `colourRandom2`.

```
var colourRandom;

function colourRandom2() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 24));
  return '#' + ('00000' + num.toString(16)).substr(-6);
}


colourRandom2();

colourRandom = 0;
```

I would like to create my own function like this. How do you this? [Here's what looks to be the code that creates the random colour block.](https://github.com/google/blockly/blob/develop/blocks/colour.ts) (line 37)

[image: Picture of Blocks]

Comment: Global variables become properties of the `window` object. So it's probably doing something like `if ("colourRandom" in window)`

Comment: If you view the source of that page, you can find a reference to `https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/dist/javascript_compressed.js`. It looks like it contains code that converts blockly blocks into JS code. Similarly there are files for conversions to Lua or PHP, written in JS.